# Access service from an injected module in Angular 1

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular 1 app with two modules, `main` and `secondary`. `secondary` is injected in `main`, and main have a `service`:

```
angular.module('main', ['secondary'])
.run(function(){
  console.log('main module run');
})
.service('mainService', function(){
  this.servMeth = function(){
    console.log('main service');
  };
});

angular.module('secondary', [])
.run(function(){
  console.log('secondary module run');
});
```

Is there a way to access `mainService` from `main` in `secondary` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to inject it in a component or other service like this:

```
angular.module('secondary', [])
.run(function(){
  console.log('secondary module run');
})
.component('secondary-component', {
  controller: ['mainService', function(mainService) {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      mainService.servMeth();
    }
  }]
});
```